# Set own event id while creating event using microsoft graph API

Tags: php, rest, events, calendar, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using **Microsoft Graph API** for integration of microsoft/outlook calendar and events.

[API Reference is here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/)
I want to specify my own custom id for event while creating an event with this rest API, but I didn't find any way to do so. It automatically created an id. Is there any way of specifying our own Id.

Following is my request:

```
POST: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events

 {
   "subject": "My event",
   "start": {
      "dateTime": "2017-10-05T07:57:45.679Z",
      "timeZone": "UTC"
  },
  "end": {
      "dateTime": "2017-10-12T07:57:45.679Z",
      "timeZone": "UTC"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No the ids are created by Exchange and are not user definable. The best option I can think of is to add an extended property to the event:

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/extended-properties-overview

Answer (score 1):

One can use the optional property **transactionId**, reference can be found at [event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/event?view=graph-rest-1.0) and [create event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Be aware this property is set when creating the event by a third party app and cannot be updated later.